# Please help for it to work for numbers 1st divisible by 2nd

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code in Python where the user is asked to enter the number of numbers in a sequence, then the numbers themselves. And finally, the program outputs the number of pairs of adjacent odd numbers. Here's a sample output:

```
Enter the length of the sequence: 
Enter number 1: 75
Enter number 2: 25
Enter number 3: 10
Enter number 4: 30
Enter number 5: 3
The number of pairs of adjacent where 1st divisible by 2nd  is :2
```

Comment: Can you share the code you've written so far in an attempt to solve this problem, and point out what part of it isn't working for you?

Comment: In question you have written adjacent odd numbers and in code you have written adjacent where 1st divisible by 2nd. Please be clear in your question

Comment: Your question, doesn't match your desired code output. Please review what you have written.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
n = int(input("Enter the length of the sequence: "))

nums = []
for i in range(n):
    nums.append(int(input(f"Enter number {i+1}: ")))

divs = 0
for j in range(n-1):
    if not nums[j] % nums[j+1]:
        divs += 1

print("The number of pairs of adjacent where 1st divisible by 2nd  is :", divs)
```

After getting inputs, I loop from beginning of `nums` to one left to the last (because there is nothing for last element to be compared to). Then compare every element is list with the one after it; If it was divisible, I add one to total number of divisibles (`divs`).

You can also use list comprehension:

```
[nums[j] % nums[j+1] for j in range(n-1)].count(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough but the below code should work, please feel free to understand some builtin functions like `enumerate`

```py
seq = int(input("Enter the length of sequence "))
list_num = []
count = 0
for i in range(1, seq+1):
  num = int(input(f"Enter number {i} "))
  list_num.append(num)

for i1, ele in enumerate(list_num):
  if i1 < (len(list_num)-1):
    if ((list_num[i1]) % list_num[i1+1]) == 0:
      count += 1
  else:
    break
print("The number of pairs of adjacent where 1st divisible by 2nd  is :",count)
```